# Encrypt a video file IOS

Tags: ios, encryption

I have an ios application that contains video files in it. I'm concerned about users with
jailbroken phones being able to rip these videos out of the app.

One of the solutions I thought might work would be to encrypt the videos,
and save it in library and at the time of playing I would decrypt it and play it ..
But the problem is since the video are of bigger size , encryption takes a long time .

I am looking for some alternatives.. please help

Comment: Will be Good if you store videos on `Server` and provide the `Url` to user and add some `Validation` through your code when some request you to play videos so without validation no video.

Comment: You don't need a jailbroken device to access any file from your app's resource bundle. Anyone can unzip your app's ipa file and extract any file they want. The ipa file is stored on a user's computer by iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a good idea to not package media like videos into your app binary. Since it has some negatives -

1. Your app size becomes big and its good to keep your app size as small as possible to enable faster download times.
2. Incase of any change in the media you would have to repackage the entire app and again submit to the app store.

So a better approach is to provide `http` links to the media in the app code. So for you you would hardcode the link in your app code like `http://mywebsite.com/myvideo.mp4`. That way its kinda secure, plus if you need to change the video all you need to do is replace this `myvideo.mp4` with the new video and your app need not be touched at all.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the issue at all. Once the video is downloaded to the user's device, it is trivial to access - even on a non-jailbroken device. All the user needs to do is backup their device with iTunes and then they can access the video from the backup on their computer.

Comment: OK, streaming would solve that issue. But anyone can determine the URL and then directly access the video. You would need to use a password protected `https` URL.

Comment: To build on video streaming thought. If the system has some form of user authentication, then play video only to logged in verified users. If there is no logging in for this website, then go for `https` with an additional cookie like authentication where a token is stored in the iOS app's `keychain`. This is as secure as it can get.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, keeping users from access video files while still allowing users to, well, access video files, tends to rely on just making it annoying enough that users decide they have better things to do.

Basically, make people jump through hoops to access a file, while your app handles that for them. Randomly generate time limited URLs in response to a request with authentication details to an secret https URL which changes regularly. Use a custom format which your app can read, but other people need to mess around with to read. Ultimately, a user can always reverse engineer your app to access whatever keys you're using, use a packet sniffer to copy the stream as the app is playing it, or one of a dozen other methods. All you can do is try to make it harder to do.